# css tables for rowspan and colspan

Tags: css

I am creating a table out of div's and need a method replicating the effect of a cell that spans 5 rows and a cell that spans 2 columns.

This is what I have for a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dwlamb/ce0haca0/1/.  Anything I have tried ends up breaking the lay-out.

If it makes it easier to figure out what I have done so far, comment out border in `.cell.empty` in the css to view all borders.

As I have stated in that fiddle, I want a div that will span the two columns. My plan is to hide the spanned row div at smaller browsers <769px and hide the two-column div at resolutions >768px

Comment: Curious if there's a reason why you can't just use a table?

Comment: @JohnTobin because of responsive design considerations and to gain more knowledge of using css to make tables.

Comment: You should describe the problem and the attempted solution in the question itself. This includes the specific trick you are trying. CSS tables have no counterpart to `rowspan` and `colspan`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`colspan` and `rowspan` are not avalaible in CSS, these are really specific to **real** table tag/elements.

You should rethink your structure/imbrication if it has some meanings :).

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jtyfF)**

```
<div class="tablelayout">
  <h1 class="cell"> title</h1>
  <div class="cell ">
    <h2 class="tablelayout">subtitle</h2>
    <div class="tablelayout">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="cell"> Cell </p>
        <p class="cell"> Cell </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="cell"> Cell </p>
        <p class="cell"> Cell </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="cell"> Cell </p>
        <p class="cell"> Cell </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`display:table-caption` is avalaible and could be used : **[DEMO 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yhCKA)**

`display:table-header-group;` is avalaible too : **[DEMO 3](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nCwye)**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, take a look at [Display Properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

In CSS3, you have ALL possibilities a table has, and then some more. You aren't using any of them, so give it a try

If you're dead set on your approach, try the Column Count property. I really don't understand your code, so for the sake of it, here's a generic sample for your 2 columns span

```
.cell{
-webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
column-count: 2;
}
```

and for rows, you can simply apply block styles. Then again, you should use the CSS display options. Way easier and a lot less trouble