# How do I col span and row span in the DIV table

Tags: html, css

I made the table with using DIV and P only.
How do I col-span or row-span in this code?

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
  <div class="row" style="display: 
    table-row;">
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">col A</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 3px;">col B
    </p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 3px;">col C
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="display: table-row;">
    <p style="display: table-cell; 
    border: solid 1px gray; padding: 3px;">apple</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">banana</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">cancel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="display: table-row;">
    <p style="display: table-cell; 
    border: solid 1px gray; padding: 3px;">analysis</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">believe</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">cry</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to merge the second and third rows of the first column. (apple and analysis)

Comment: have you considered CSS Grid Layout ?

Comment: With difficulty. Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel when tables exist for tabular data? And if you really don't want to use tables, consider `flexbox`. `flex-basis` in particular would be useful for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css tables for rowspan and colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334593/css-tables-for-rowspan-and-colspan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the border like this :

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
  <div class="row" style="display: 
    table-row;">
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">col A</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 3px;">col B
    </p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 3px;">col C
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="display: table-row;">
    <p style="display: table-cell; 
    border: solid 1px gray; padding: 3px;border-bottom:none;">apple</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">banana</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">cancel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="display: table-row;">
    <p style="display: table-cell; 
    border: solid 1px gray; padding: 3px;border-top:none;">analysis</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">believe</p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 
    3px;">cry</p>
  </div>
</div>
```